# Codeigniter web application working fine with all devices only for few iphones session is not working

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter

**Codeigniter web application working fine with all devices only for few iphones session is not working**

My config file code snippet:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

**only for few iphone mobiles devices, session is not working**

May be this issue is solved by "Native Session Class"

But I want to know how to replace "Session Class" With "Native Session Class" in short (without disturbing to project functionalities)

please suggest me ideas or changes to resolve this issue.

Comment: _“May be this issue is solved by "Native Session Class"”_ - and maybe it isn’t. _“please suggest me ideas or changes to resolve this issue.”_ - you boast 5+ years of PHP experience on your profile, so I think you should be able to do a bit better than that. Start by properly analyzing what the problem actually _is_. My guess would be that it is probably simply a matter of rejection of the session cookie.

Comment: @CBroe yes bro.. but issues only on some iphone devices.. its working fine with our side iphone devices.. problem is that I could not analyze the relevant devices settings.. If you have any strong guess then please

Comment: The strong guess is and remains, that it is likely a problem with the acceptance of the session cookie. We can’t debug on these devices any more than you can, so you will have to go and gather more information from the affected users.

Comment: Like @CBroe says, any ideas from our side would require a lot more information from the affected devices. I second him that this looks like an issue of rejected session cookies. The only relevant and evident thing that may be affecting you (although I'm not sure why it would only affect a subset of iphone users) is that you have two `sess_save_path` entries that may be conflicting. For starters, remove the `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` entry and use something other than `BASEPATH . 'cache/';` for the other. The `cache` directory is not meant to store session information